# Special characters are correctly displayed only when inserted from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, navicat

I have table `Users` (with UTF8 character set and **utf8_general_ci** collation) which has `lastName` column (same character set and collation as table). When I insert my name (Štěrba) into this table and column directly from *Navicat for MySQL*, it's correctly displayed in Navicat, but badly in browser (output document is UTF8 and after `mysql_connect()` I also use `SET CHARACTER SET utf8`):

[image: Correctly in Navicat, wrongly in browser]

But when I do this insert from PHP with this query:

```
INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName) values ('Pavel', 'Štěrba');
```

it's displayed correctly in browser, but in Navicat it's saved like this:

[image: Wrongly in Navicat, correctly in browser]

Obviously, I can't edit it directly from navicat because I will break it... Have you got any idea, why this happen? Did I miss encoding somewhere? Or it's issue with Navicat? Thanks for tips!

Comment: looks like a navicat issue, but i have never used it

Comment: It's displayed in phpMyAdmin same way as in Navicat.

Comment: What character set (charset) is Navicat using? From your description it sounds like Navicat is using an incorrect charset (probably ISO-8859-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are high YOU are doing it wrong, and not the tools everyone uses.

Do not fiddle with the encoding setting via queries! Use [mysql_set_charset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php).

You have to repair all entries in your database that got there via PHP.

Note that "SET CHARACTER SET" is wrong, although it sounds like the right thing. If you cannot use the above PHP function, all you should do is use "SET NAMES utf8" only!

Comment: Even when I don't use query and do it with `mysql_set_charset()`, I still have broken characters when lastName is added directly from Navicat...

Comment: According to my another progress, I need to fix displaying of those characters, because when I save it via PHP, for example "Š" is saved in database as "A" and this break ordering...

Comment: You should make sure that UTF-8 encoding is used everywhere. Is it in a) the HTTP `Content-type` header, b) the HTML `<meta>` tag and c) in the `accept-encoding` form attribute?

Comment: Oh, it was my fault, because in my connect function was return before `mysql_set_charset()`... Stupid mistake... Anyway, this function and your solution fix it, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

use `SET NAMES utf8` also after `SET CHARACTER SET utf8`

i hope this help